# iMac unable to boot from USB

Tags: macos, imac

I have an iMac with pure Windows 10 installed (not bootcamp).

To re-install macOS, I have downloaded the .DMG file of Big Sur.

Then I used Acute's TransMac with my ADATA 32GB to:

1. Format Disc for Mac
2. Restore with Disc Image

Then, I rebooted the machine and pressed OPTION key. The Startup Manager appeared, and my USB was not there. I just had the internal HDD to select.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Precisely which iMac? Why not just use Internet Recovery? How did you manage to download Big Sur without a Mac? That's not possible unless you use a… *'non-authoritative'* source.

Comment: I'm not using Internet Recovery because I don't want to. And how and where I've downloaded the DMG is not related to my issue. Thanks.

Comment: OK, then have fun fumbling through it your own way. There's not enough information for anyone to answer this. Random interweb downloads & non-standard setups… vs. 'the easy way'. Your call. Basically, it doesn't recognise the USB because you did something wrong… but you're not giving us any clue as to what that may be.

Comment: You didn't ask anything about USB - while I've explained how it is prepared. Again, the source of DMG has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: OK. Wish you luck. Your question as it stands cannot be answered. I'm done, unless you add pertinent information to your question. As you're hiding the source of your .dmg & Apple don't release full OSes as .dmg files, you're just fumbling with 3rd party constructs, so there's nothing anyone can do to help.

Comment: It is downloaded from Apple Store on a Mac by a friend, and shared with me on OneDrive, so it's not from a non-authoritative source.

Comment: Please add any pertinent information to your question - including the very basic "which iMac". As I already said, OS installers are not normally issued as .dmg files, so something just doesn't ring true. You're being evasive & I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, post your iMac model, as Tetsujin asked. There are machines that will not boot from USB sources without modification to the firmware security settings.

Tetsujin is absolutely correct. As they pointed out, there's no such thing as an Big Sur DMG. Big Sur is an .app download through the App Store, Internet Recovery and/or Software Update. If you downloaded a DMG from anywhere other than these sources, the presumption is that you don't have a valid Big Sur. For all we know, somebody cloned their own machine, which, in the best of circumstances, could be a clone of an M1 system, which will do you absolutely no good on your Intel iMac.

Once you obtain an official Big Sur release, from another Mac obviously, you can create a proper bootable installer USB using the embedded createinstallmedia command from the app bundle. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372. You can use that USB stick to boot any Mac that's compatible with Big Sur - assuming firmware security allows you to boot from USB. Any other preparation method does not work. That includes whatever TransMac is doing.

Let's presume that your DMG is a clone of a freshly installed system that's pristine. The primary reason that it doesn't work is that you haven't connected an installer image. As far as the macOS firmware is concerned, you've just connected a regular old USB stick. There's nothing there to indicate that it can install anything. What's more likely is that TransMac didn't prepare the USB stick properly, with the APFS file system and containers.

This is why Tetsujin and I would both recommend using Internet Recovery, whether you like it or not. Or go to the Apple Store yourself, and ask them to create proper installer media for you.

Comment: It is very easy to extract the DMG file from downloaded app.

Comment: Instructions already in the link in the answer, how to use `createinstallmedia`. A dmg is no use to you do do this, it is not bootable. if you don't have another Mac to use `createinstallmedia` then just use Internet Recovery. We ***still*** need to know exactly what Mac model to be able to help properly. If, as I suspect due to your reticence in supplying relevant information, you're actually trying to get this onto a "PC" then this is not the way to do it at all. It will not work.